# Spark Dataframe join where column is null

Tags: java, apache-spark, join, dataframe, where-clause

Im trying to recreate a Left Outer Join in Spark. The join also excludes NULL values in the right table. The thought behind this is: The left table provides new records. I need to check if there's any new data and load the selection into a new dataframe.

**SQL as reference (this works):**

```
SELECT 
primary_key,
attribute_1, 
attribute_2
FROM
left_table l
LEFT JOIN right_table r ON l.primary_key = r.foreign_key 
WHERE r.foreign_key IS NULL
```

**Java Dataframe Join**

```
Dataset<Row> joined = left_table.alias("l").join(right_table.alias("r"), left_table.col("primary_key").equalTo(right_table.col("foreign_key")), "left_outer");
```

**Result**

```
+--------------------+-----------+-------+-----+
|         primary_key|foreign_key|attr_1 |attr2|
+--------------------+-----------+-------+-----+
|c6d2f6791d7e6127d...|       null|   null| null|      
|485e86b2b77ebd787...|       null|   null| null|     
|8c7e1ac10cb1650e5...|       null|   null| null|
```

The Join itself works but i still get the null values. The next thing i tried was adding a where clause (.where(right_table.col("foreign_key").isNull());). This just leaves me with an empty dataframe.

How can i insert a where-clause/filter to exlude the null values?

Comment: Try `Dataset<Row> joined = left_table.join(right_table, left_table(col("primary_key")) === right_table(col("foreign_key")), "inner");`

Comment: @RameshMaharjan It's impossible in Java, Java doesn't have custom operators

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `IS NULL`, not `IS NOT NULL`?